# Can a martial character ready the same maneuver multiple times simultaneously?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle, martial

All the martial classes from ToB have different methods of preparing and re-preparing maneuvers, but the basic mechanics are pretty much the same for all of them (well, maybe just two, except the crusader).

**Can a martial artist ready 2+ of the same maneuver at the same time?** I've heard people say "no", but RaW looks pretty much the opposite to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, a given martial maneuver can not be readied more than once.

The reason for this confusion is that maneuvers and spells are similar enough in their implementation to make it easy to miss the few ways in which they are different - the ability to prepare a spell more than once being one of them. As seen on page 178 of the Player's Handbook:

> [A prepared spellcaster] can prepare the same spell more than once, but each preparation counts as one spell toward her daily limit.

The important part is that no equivalent clause exists for martial initiators.

Having defeated the mental trap of assuming that maneuvers work something like spells, we can re-examine what the text actually says about maneuvers.

ToB page 22 (Warblade):

> You begin an encounter with all your readied maneuvers unexpended, regardless of how many times you might have already used them since you chose them. When you initiate a maneuver, you expend it for the current encounter, so each of your readied maneuvers can be used once per encounter

ToB page 38 (Blade Magic):

> maneuvers require preparation in the form of exercise, prayer, meditation, or simple mental rehearsal. Therefore, you must choose a selection of readied maneuvers from all the maneuvers you know. Only your readied maneuvers are available for immediate use.

Similar language is used throughout the book. There is no reference to "maneuver slots" or similar terms that are used in Vancian spellcasting.

Instead, the book consistently refers to a maneuver as either known or not known, readied or not readied (and in the case of the Crusader, granted or not granted). There is a defined way for a spellcaster to "prepare the same spell more than once", but maneuvers do not inherit that property.

The act of readying maneuvers is more like the one of iterating through your maneuvers known, and deciding which of them have the "ready" flag and which of them don't than the one of loading a gun with spell bullets, as is the case with prepared spellcasters.

Maneuvers are either ready for use or they are not - a binary condition. There is no defined way a maneuver can be "ready twice".

For those who place faith in [the official FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ask/20060830a&dcmp=ILC-RSSDND), it agrees with this reading.

Answer (score 1):

## Single-classed, no

@Ernir covers this well.

## Multiclassed, maybe

The question is whether or not a maneuvers that you know are separated by the classes you are in or not. In other words, does a Crusader/Warblade have separate Crusader maneuvers and Warblade maneuvers, or just a single list of maneuvers? The book is not entirely clear.

Certainly, the Crusader and Warblade classes get access to some different disciplines (Devoted Spirit for Crusader; Diamond Mind, Iron Heart, and Tiger Claw for Warblade), but those restrictions are on which maneuvers they can learn as a part of leveling in those classes, not the maneuvers they can know. After all, they can use Martial Study or prestige class levels to get maneuvers from other disciplines.

And they definitely maintain separate lists of readied maneuvers, which affect how each maneuver is recovered and how many maneuvers can be readied at once. The book wouldn’t make any sense otherwise.

But the question remains whether or not the lists of maneuvers *known* are kept separated.

If they are not, then you cannot ever ready a maneuver more than once, because once you know the maneuver you know it and that’s the end of it. However, that also means that you can ready maneuvers that you “learned” from one class as a maneuver from the other class (assuming you have a high enough Initiator Level in the second class). For instance, a Crusader 8/Warblade 1 could learn *iron heart surge* (a 3rd-level Iron Heart maneuver, requires IL 5) with that Warblade level (½×8+1=5), but then ready it as one of his Crusader maneuvers (taking advantage of the Crusader’s generally-superior recovery mechanic).

If the lists *are* separated, however, so that you have your Warblade maneuvers known and your Crusader maneuvers known and every maneuver you learn is added to one or the other and cannot be readied from the opposite class, then you could learn the same maneuver with both classes: it only appears on a maneuvers known list once. And then you could ready it with each class, effectively readying it twice.

The book is not clear on this. The most common way to play, that I’ve seen, is actually a logically-inconsistent mix: you can not ready another class’s maneuvers but you can’t relearn or reready a maneuver that you know from another class either, as if the lists were both separate and combined at the same time. This, to me, is not a tenable position, however: the two options are mutually exclusive and half-one-way-half-the-other results in a kind of weird Schrödinger’s maneuver list.

Comment: To quote the sage: "Q: Another multiclass question. Can a multiclassed martial adept (eg. Swordsage/Warblade) choose/and or ready the same maneuver for each of it's classes (provided you have access to the same maneuver)? And if you gain a maneuver in one class, can you use it as a prerequisite in gaining a maneuver in the other class?
A: No, you can only ever learn/ready a maneuver once. If you gain a maneuver in one class it can indeed fulfill prerequisites in another class!" So your multiclass option doesn't work

Comment: @TheAmusedMuse False, because the sage had zero authority and zero editorial oversight. He was very frequently wrong, and the official rules are very clear that if he says anything that goes beyond literally explaining the rules as they stand (i.e. any modification, contradiction, qualification, or extension), that is to be ignored under the official rules (see the note at the top of each errata file). His statements here reflect absolutely *nothing* beyond the quick response he jotted down after skimming *Tome of Battle*. Wizards did not give him authority to make amendments to the rules.

Answer (score 1):

> When you initiate a maneuver, you expend it for the current encounter, so each of your readied maneuvers can be used once per encounter

You expend the maneuver for the combat. Not the maneuver slot.

The way I see it, if you could ready 3 of the same maneuver, when you would use any of them, the maneuver would be marked as expended and you wouldn't be able to use any of the 3 copies.

For the same reason, if you somehow trade off an expended maneuver for one you have not used, you can use it right away.

So whether you can ready them or not is irrelevant, as you would not be able to use them more than once.

**EDIT:**

I have thought of a situation where this might be relevant:

> Imagine you are multiclassing warblade and crusader and there is a maneuver you want to continuously use during battle.
>
> You could ready the maneuver for crusader and warblade and use it since the 1st turn from the warblade pool, then try and get it from the random maneuvers you get each turn.

In that case, I'm gonna say there is nothing stopping you from readying that maneuver more than once (once for each class, that is. Otherwise, the maneuver won't work).

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can because, although others have pointed out that RAW makes no mention of being able to do this, there is no statement saying you can cannot. The text reads:

ToB page 22 (Warblade):

> You begin an encounter with all your readied maneuvers unexpended, regardless of how many times you might have already used them since you chose them. When you initiate a maneuver, you expend it for the current encounter, so each of your readied maneuvers can be used once per encounter

There is no line saying you cannot ready the same maneuver multiple times. The same can be said for ToB page 38 (Blade Magic):

> maneuvers require preparation in the form of exercise, prayer, meditation, or simple mental rehearsal. Therefore, **you must choose a selection of readied maneuvers from all the maneuvers you know. Only your readied maneuvers are available for immediate use.**

Who is to say from this that your readied maneuvers could not all be the same one? If I choose to ready dance of the mongoose 8 times as a 12th level Swordsage, I have met all criteria outlined: **I have chosen a selection of readied maneuvers 
from all the ones I know.**

While it is true that there are no "Maneuver slots" and maneuvers DO NOT work like spells, RAW doesn't say anything about not being able to use the same maneuver twice when you've chosen what you ready. The only restriction is having to know the maneuver.

Comment: When the game says you can, you can. When the game says you can't, you can't. When the game doesn't say at all, you usually can't.

Comment: @HeyICanChan The game doesn't *say* that you can move around by walking during a full moon, so by that logic, moon comes up, legs stop working.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon But the game *does* allow for ground movement with specific restrictions that don't include your list. Lacking a fly speed, though, doesn't enable flight.

Comment: @HeyICanChan The flight thing is apples-to-oranges. The initiator class *does* allow for maneuvers to be readied, just as the game does allow for ground movement. It also spells out restrictions on that readying, and just as ground speed doesn't include a full moon on its restriction list, the initiator rules do not include "one instance of each maneuver" on its restriction list.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon Hey, *you* appled-to-oranged first! :-) But the issue's fundamental with *ToB*: it uses *real* words--like *ready* and *change*--in *real* ways instead of in game ways. Seriously, in the real world if something is *ready* it just can't be readied *again* unless it's somehow made not ready after it was ready. [Downvote](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/34754/8610) me if you want, but a lot of the weirdness of *ToB* disappears if the book's read with real language in mind rather than gaming language.